# How to get/debug parameter dictionary on json payload on mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC5 - Action that used to work just fine. Now it doesn't. We changed some things, updated the packages, etc. 
Because that Action isn't called quite often we are unsure what caused the problem.

I receive the following Error:

> System.ArgumentException: The parameters dictionary contains a null
>   entry for parameter 'closureInTime' of non-nullable type
>   'System.Boolean' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Close(Int32,
>   Boolean, Boolean, Int32, Int32, Int32, Boolean)' in
>   'ProjectController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a
>   nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.

As the route seems to find the correct Action, but not the correct parameters I want to find out if I can debug anywhere, what parameters actually be sent to my MVC-Application before it is matched to my Action.

**Is there a way to debug into the route finding and receive the dictionary with the parameters before the actual routing happens?**

We use attribute Routing (But the parameters are not defined within the route, but are "normal" parameters)

The Parameters are *not* sent using Forms but via Json. (Request payload: `{"closureInTime":true,"closureInBudget":true,"createNewProject":false,"successFactor":0,"closureGoal":77,"closureEffort":77})`

I do not provide code, because there was no change in the Action-Header. I do not need help to solve this specific issue, but to "sniff" into the route-decision.